# DRF + React is Session auth usable?

Tags: django, reactjs

I am trying to use Session auth in Django with React. All my GET REST calls are being reject with status 403. I probably have to send `sessionid`in headers, but `sessionid` cookie is HTTP only, so my JS code gets a null value when reading it. If I set the cookie to not be HTTP-only anymore, I can read it and send it in headers, but still seing the same problem.
Note: the view which includes the React app has a path /app, the REST api path is /api. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually related to the `fetch` library I am using for making API calls. In order to send the sessionid automatically, `credentials: include` must be added in options.